# Draggable elements on mobile using vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, game-development

I coded a simple candy crush game using the attributte "Draggable".

Only when I finished it,I noticed it doesn´t work on mobile browser and that´s my big focus. The game I'm creating is for a presentation and the people are gonna play it with their phones, so it´s not important that it works on desktop

I searched a little about "tocuhmove" that works on mobile, but I coundn´t find a way to fit it in the code I already have and since I´m still a biginner in progamming and this is the first game I'm coding, it´s been difficult

Is there a way that I can "translate" the code I already have into something mobile-frindly without losing its logic and rules?

Thank you in advance for your help!

```
let colorBeingDragged 
  let colorBeingReplaced
  let squareIdBeingDragged
  let squareIdBeingReplaced

  squares.forEach(square => square.addEventListener('dragstart', dragStart))
  squares.forEach(square => square.addEventListener('dragend', dragEnd))
  squares.forEach(square => square.addEventListener('dragover', dragOver))
  squares.forEach(square => square.addEventListener('dragenter', dragEnter))
  // squares.forEach(square => square.addEventListener('dragleave', dragLeave))
  squares.forEach(square => square.addEventListener('drop', dragDrop))
  

  function dragStart() {
    colorBeingDragged = this.style.backgroundColor
    squareIdBeingDragged = parseInt(this.id)

    console.log(colorBeingDragged)
    console.log(this.id, 'dragstart')
  }

  function dragOver(e) {
    e.preventDefault()

    console.log(this.id, 'dragover')
  }

  function dragEnter(e) {
    e.preventDefault()

    console.log(this.id, 'dragenter')
  }

  // function dragLeave() {
    
  //   console.log(this.id, 'dragleave')
  // }

  
  function dragDrop() {
    console.log('dragdrop')

    colorBeingReplaced = this.style.backgroundColor
    squareIdBeingReplaced = parseInt(this.id)
    this.style.backgroundColor = colorBeingDragged
    squares[squareIdBeingDragged].style.backgroundColor = colorBeingReplaced
    
    
  }
  
  function dragEnd() {
    
    console.log(this.id, 'dragend')
    
    //what is a valid move
    let validMoves = [squareIdBeingDragged -1, 
      squareIdBeingDragged -width, 
      squareIdBeingDragged +1, 
      squareIdBeingDragged +width
    ]

    let validMove = validMoves.includes(squareIdBeingReplaced)

    if (squareIdBeingReplaced && validMove) {
      squareIdBeingReplaced = null
    } else if (squareIdBeingReplaced && !validMove) {
      squares[squareIdBeingReplaced].style.backgroundColor = colorBeingReplaced
      squares[squareIdBeingDragged].style.backgroundColor = colorBeingDragged
    } else   {
      squares[squareIdBeingDragged].style.backgroundColor = colorBeingDragged
    }
  }
```

Comment: You would need to use the [`Touch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch) API instead, e.g: `touchstart`, `touchend`, `touchcancel`, `touchleave`, `touchmove` event listeners. But an easier option might be to just use a third-party library ([examples](https://www.cssscript.com/best-drag-drop-javascript-libraries/)). You could also try using a polyfill (like [this one](https://github.com/timruffles/mobile-drag-drop)), but still support seems patchy.

Comment: You'll need to share the rest of your code, as it's not possible to run it with just that snippet.

Comment: @Lissy93 https://github.com/mariabsouza/zurich-game.git

Comment: @Lissy93 I've been reading about the touch API but I'm suffering to make it fit into what I already have